# Sorting RealmResult in custom order

Tags: java, android, realm

I have `RealmResult` of custom type `Playlist`. Each `Playlist` have a filed `playlistTypeId` which can be either 1, 2, or 3. I'd like to sort objects in `RealmResult` in the following order: 2, 1, 3. How can I do that?

Comment: can you give us the full order ?
2,1,3,4,5,6,8,7,9??

Comment: By having a second field that indicates position, and sort based on that instead. I mean, `2,1,3` isn't exactly *sorted*.

Comment: I may have expressed myself incorrectly. There are N playlists and each is of type 1, 2 or 3. I'd like the RealmResults to be rearranged so that the ones of type 2 go first, the ones of type 1 go second and the ones of type 3 go third on the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom sorting is unfortunately not supported. Mostly for performance reasons as we would have to round-trip to Java for each element in the collection being sorted. You can follow this issue for updates on the situation: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2313

Right now, you would need to sort the RealmResults yourself, but you need to copy all elements from the RealmResults first:

```
RealmResults<Person> results = realm.where(Person.class).findAll();
List<Person> inmemResults = new ArrayList<>();
inmemResults.addAll(results);
Collections.sort(inmemResults, customSort);
```